# Draw A Diamond, A Box, And A Vertical Line With While & For Loops, AND Switch Statements-Java

Tags: java, for-loop, while-loop, switch-statement

I wrestled with this for a couple of weeks now, and just can't figure this out. My assignment is to ask the user to input a number less than 20. If the input is 5,11, or 15, the program is to draw a diamond. 3,9, or 17 it draws a box(just the outline). Anything else, it is to draw a vertical line of the same height as the input number. We had to write a method for the diamond that accepts an integer & returns a string(using a while loop), the same for the box(using a for loop) & vertical line. Those methods do not output. We are also required to use the drawHLine method the teacher created.
Then write a method asking for the input, which used a class called IO that we'd previously written for another assignment. We are to use a switch statement to determine which shape to draw.
My problem is that, I've worked out the methods which create the top half of my diamond, as well as the one for the box. But I cannot figure out how to then draw the bottom half.
Here's my working IO class:

```
/*
 * This is a stand alone utility package to be used over again.
 */

package util;

/**
 *
 * @author Michael
 */
import java.awt.Font;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

/* getInput asks for input from GUI, then outputs to a Dialog box.
*getConsoleInput uses the console to ask for input, then outputs 
*it to the console.
*/
public class IO {

    public static Scanner getInput( String prompt){
        String s = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(prompt);
        return new Scanner(s);
                }
 /* Defines the getConsoleInput method, which requests input from the 
  *console, then returns output through the console.
  */

    public static Scanner getConsoleInput(String prompt ){
        System.out.println(prompt);
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        return input;
    }
    /*Defines the showMessage method, which outputs to a Dialog Box
    */            

    public static void showMessage(String s){
        System.out.println(s);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, s);
    }
    /*Defines the overloaded showMessage method, which outputs to a Dialog Box,
    but changes the text from whatever is initially the default.
    */
    public static void showMessage(String output,String title ) {
            System.out.println(output);
            JTextArea jta = new JTextArea(title);
            jta.setFont(
            new Font("Verdana", 
                   Font.BOLD, 14));
               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, jta);
    }
}
```

And here is what I have so far of the program:

```
/*
 * The purpose of this program is to ask the user to enter a positive odd
 * number less than 20, then depending on the number entered, draw either 
 * a diamond (outline only), a box(outline only), or a verticle line.
 */

/**
 *
 * @author Michael Davis
 */
import util.IO;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Assignment5 {

    public static String drawHLine(int n, char ch) {
        String result = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            result += ch;
        }
        return result;

    }

    public static String drawDiamond(int n) {
        String result = "";
        int x = 1;
        int y = 1;
        int spaces = n / 2;
        while (x <= n) {
            result += drawHLine(spaces, ' ')
                    + drawHLine(x, '*') + "\n";
            x += 2;
            spaces--;
        }

        while ( y>=1){
             result += drawHLine(spaces, ' ') +
                    drawHLine(y, '*') + "\n";
        y -=2;
        spaces++; 
        return result;
    }
    }


/* 

 public static String drawBox(int n) {
 String result = "";
 int x = 0;
 while (x <= n) {
 for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
 if (j == 0 || x == 0) {
 result += " *";
 }
 }
 result += "\n";
 x++;
 }
 return result;
 }
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = IO.getInput("Please enter a number less than 20");
        int choice = input.nextInt();
        switch (choice) {
            case 5:
            case 11:
            case 15:
                IO.showMessage(drawDiamond(choice) , "Diamond");
                break;
            /*
             case 3:
             case 9:
             case 17:
             IO.showMessage(drawBox(choice), "Box");
             break;
             */
        }
        System.exit(0);
    }

}
```

Comment: Your `y` starts from 1 instead of the proper number of asterisks for the middle of the diamonds.

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't work because you initialize the `y` variable to 1. Since this variable describes the remaining width of a line in the bottom half of the diamond, its initial value needs to be the width of the diamond.